# Create PDF file from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, jspdf

I am trying to create an PDF file from a PHP page with `jsPDF` but it is not working and I dont know whats wrong.

Can someone help me?

First I have a `Iframe`. The page I want to convert is displayed in the Iframe:

**Iframe:**

```
<?php
    <iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="100%" height="1160px" frameborder="0" src="./page.php?id=' . $_GET['id'] . '"></iframe>
    <button id="cmd">Button</button>
?>
```

When I hit `Button` the following script should convert the page to PDF

**Script**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function(element, renderer){
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('frame').get(0), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170, 
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });

    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
</script>
```

But when I hit `Button`. Nothing is happening. Does someone know whats wrong?

Comment: You don't have any button with id `cmd`, nor a function with the name `cmd`.

Comment: @Arg0n. It is creating a PDF page now. But the page is empty

Answer (score 6):

You must be get html of iframe, so use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) function and then get `documentElement` of iframe:

```
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="100%" height="1160px" frameborder="0" src="http://localhost/"></iframe>
<button id="cmd">Button</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function(element, renderer){
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#frame').contents().find('html').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170, 
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });

    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
</script>
```

Note: If your iframe source page or part of it protected with `x-frame-options` header, you cannot access to html of it.

Comment: It isn't doing anything

Comment: It is creating an empty pdf file when I write: `doc.fromHTML($('iframe')`. The ID and NAMe of the iframe is `frame`. When I change `doc.fromHTML($('iframe')` to `doc.fromHTML($('frame')` it is not creating anymore

Comment: Try  `doc.fromHTML($('#iframe').contents()[0].documentElement`

Comment: It's still not creating a file. Maybe it is necessary for the answer. This is how the content of the iframe looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/ss6780qn/

Comment: I saw your edit. It is creating a pdf file, but the PDF file is empty

Comment: I updated my answer and it runs successfully on localhost. But with https://jsfiddle.net/ss6780qn/ it has error, because that page protected from accessing cross-origin. Are you try it locally?

Comment: Wait. It has a content now. When I click for the first time the script creates an empty PDF file. When I click again I get a PDF file with data.

Comment: Also the PDF file looks not not the same. The style looks different than the content of the Iframe

Comment: jsPDF doesn't support css. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460035/jspdf-cant-get-any-styling-to-work

Comment: So I need to change the HTML page then?

Comment: Do you have a solution for the new problem? That the script is first is creating an empty PDF file and the second time an filled PDF file?

Comment: Iframe needs to load completely, is it loaded?

Comment: Yes, it is loaded

Comment: jsPDF has some function for set styles like [`setFontSize()`](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#setFontSize), but it's limited!

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="cmd()">Button</button>
```

Change this to

```
<button id="cmd">Button</button>
```

You are calling the click event in JS on the id. Or change the onclick event to a function with the name cmd.

Comment: Still nothing is happening

Comment: By nothing is happening can you see the button? I see you've put HTML inside PHP tags. You should put the GET in PHP. If you can see the button then put some logging inside the click event and see if its triggering.

Comment: I forgot to delete the `()`. Now it is creating a PDF page. But the PDF is empty

Comment: Not sure but maybe change $('frame') to $('#frame')

Comment: No, its still empty

Comment: Sorry but I have never used the package you are using but I am just testing now. Here is a similar question that relates to your new problem that may help in the meantime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184659/cannot-make-pdf-from-html-div-by-jspdf

Comment: Here someone is trying to do what you are doing. I haven't tested it but it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415506/download-pdf-file-from-an-iframe-content-with-jspdf

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, jsPDF has limitations and/or bugs. It has problems with complex tables (especially with colspans). It throws javascript errors which stops the renderer which is why you're getting blank pdfs.

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/516

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/595

A fork has been posted here: https://github.com/jutunen/jsPDF-table_2 but I'm not sure if it addresses other limitations of jsPDF.